# Separate text using regex

Tags: regex

I have a string like

```
abcdefangners
```

and a set of numbers that specifies how to group the above string, such as

```
3,4
```

In this case, the output should be

```
abc,defa,gners
```

Is something like this possible using regex? I have one option of using a loop to get the comparisons of the set one by one, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:-

```
/(.{3})(.{4})(.*)/
```

This would give you the substrings which you'd then have to join together.

You'd have to create the regexp for each set of numbers so it would not be as easy as other methods of string manipulation.

Comment: The problem here is that the set of numbers to group the strings, is not the same, it could also be 1,1,1 or something different

Comment: That's why I said this is not the best way. You have to create regex on the fly. It would be better to use normal string splitting. Eg with substring.